# How to fix game in BlueStacks which is displaying graphics in black?

Tags: graphics-card, virtualization, king-of-avalon-dragon-warfare

When running KoA in [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) Android emulator on macOS Sierra (MacBook Pro), most of the graphics have black patches, although it works fine on the phone.

[image: BlueStacks, King of Avalon, black graphics]

I've [reported the problem in BlueStacks support](https://bluestacks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115009400566-King-of-Avalon-problem-with-graphics), but they're not supporting Mac without even investigating the issue. Although maybe there is some simpler solution or hack which somebody came across, since BlueStacks operates in VirtualBox environment running Android OS, so maybe there are some tweaks to fix this issue.

There is a related issue: [Why Am I Getting Black Screen On BlueStacks?](https://bluestacks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203937139-Why-am-I-getting-Black-screen-on-BlueStacks-) and [Why Am I Getting Black Patches On Clash Of Clans?](https://bluestacks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204316669-Why-am-I-getting-Black-patches-on-Clash-of-Clans-)

---

In `~Library/BlueStacks/Android` I've got some `.vdi` along with `Android.vbox`.

I've tried to edit `Android.vbox` manually (which is in XML format) and enabled 2D and 3D acceleration, so the line is as below:

```
<Display VRAMSize="12" monitorCount="1" accelerate3D="true" accelerate2DVideo="true"/>
```

However after BlueStacks restart, it didn't help.

Comment: Amazingly enough, BlueStacks has a support entry directly related to "blackscreen" issues: https://bluestacks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203937139-Why-am-I-getting-Black-screen-on-BlueStacks-     but that aside, on your support ticket you listed that you were running it on macOS Sierra, and then said you were running it on Windows when they said it wasn't supported. Your screenshot shows a mac screen...so maybe there's an integrity issue here you need to clear up before you can get real solvency?

Comment: I'm using MacBook Pro, so you mean physical graphics card, or some virtualized drivers in the VBox? Thanks for the links anyway, I'll try to read it, maybe I'll get some new ideas.

Comment: Sort of. It depends on how you're attempting to virtualize. If BlueStacks isn't supported in a Mac, and you're using a Mac to emulate windows and then to emulate Android, there's no real mystery as to why you're having issues here, really.

Comment: I can see some `.vdi` files in `~Library/BlueStacks/Android`, so one potential solution is to open them in VirtualBox, and do some modifications, maybe changing the emulated graphic drivers or something. I'm not sure. But I think it can be solved, but I don't know yet how. I think I've some idea, I'll update if I find something.

Comment: Keep in mind that not everything is limited by the code. You're working with hardware and a massive set of variables - and you have to consider why there's no Mac support before you fiddle with the files. If you're only playing this one game, sure, but what do those files do outside the parameters of the program within the OS?

Comment: Did enable `accelerate3D="true" accelerate2DVideo="true"` in `Android.vbox`, which was close, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: This sounds more like an issue trying to run an already unstable (in my experience) platform on something that doesn't support it.  This isn't really a gaming problem; and I'm not sure if anyone can really help you.

Comment: BlueStacks is basically running Android OS within virtualized environment via VirtualBox, so theoretically this can be run directly without BlueStacks it-self, and VirtualBox is supported on macOS. Although I cannot test it, since recently I've got unrelated VirtualBox kernel crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in the recent version of BlueStacks 4.

[image: Bluestacks - King of Avalon game - Collect Resources]
[image: Bluestacks - King of Avalon game - Military Tent]
[image: Bluestacks - King of Avalon game - Collect Resources - Combo Key]

See also:

- [King of Avalon Combat 101 Guide](https://www.bluestacks.com/blog/game-guides/king-of-avalon-combat-guide-en.html)
- [Combo Key on BlueStacks 4.2: Record and Replay an Action with a Single Key](https://www.bluestacks.com/blog/bluestacks-exclusives/combo-key-bluestacks-record-replay-action-single-key-en.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem exists only on macOS and probably on Linux as well. However, I was able to run [BlueStacks App Player on Windows 2012 virtual machine on Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01N0E0YYZ) and connected to it via the *Remote Desktop* app client on macOS and the graphics seem to works fine. It works slow on a medium type of instance but should work a bit faster on the large one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the potential solution using `VBoxManage` command by enabling 2D and 3D acceleration:

```
$ VBoxManage list vms
"Android" {87bb8c18-a755-46c6-ba82-2a0deb17bac3}
$ VBoxManage modifyvm Android --accelerate3d on --accelerate2dvideo on --vram 64 --memory 1024
$ VBoxManage showvminfo Android
...
3D Acceleration: on
2D Video Acceleration: on
...
$ VBoxManage startvm Android
```

Although I cannot test it end-to-end, since I've got [kernel crash](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16805) on `startvm` command (which is not related to above settings), although it doesn't work when running BlueStacks directly. But it's worth if somebody can test it out.